# jQuery animate a div while subsequently fading triggers in and out

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, image, fadein, fadeout

I've got a menu bar that slides across the page when an image is clicked, and slides back when an alternate image is clicked. I'd like to included fading the just-clicked image out and fading the unclicked image in as the menu bar is animated. I'm sure this can be done with a dynamic function.. but it's beyond my understanding.

Thank you for your help!

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="trigger_left">
        <img class="arrow_small" src="images/left_small.png" alt="slide menu out" />
    </div>
    <div id="trigger_right">
        <img class="arrow_small" src="images/right_small.png" alt="slide menu in" />
    </div>
    <div id="slider">
         <p>This is Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Page Load
    $('#slider').css({
        width: '30px'
    });
    // Navigation drop down menu
    $('#trigger_left').click(function() {
        $('#slider').animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, 1500);
    });
    $('#trigger_right').click(function() {
        $('#slider').animate({
            width: '30px',
        }, 1500);
        }

    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you might want to cache your jQuery objects to improve the performance and readability, then you might want to add the `.stop()` method to halt current animation and fire new one from current point rather then seeing animations queueing and looping and acting weird. then add the `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` on the triggers when click occurs. Ah and you should get used to using `.bind()` rather then `.click()`, `.keydown()` etc. as these are aliases to bind method so it's more efficient to use bind directly. Apart of that it's easier to use events namespaces with bind and more. [`Check the jQuery API!`](http://api.jquery.com)

```
var trigger_left = $('#trigger_left'),
    trigger_right = $('#trigger_right'),
    slider = $('#slider');

slider[0].style.width = "30px"; // and use native js where you can 
        //- it speeds things up and prepares you for when you can't use jQ :)

trigger_left.bind('click', function() {
    trigger_left.stop().fadeOut();
    trigger_right.stop().fadeIn();
    slider.stop().animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, 1500);
});
trigger_right.bind('click', function() {
    trigger_right.stop().fadeOut();
    trigger_left.stop().fadeIn();
    slider.stop().animate({
        width: '30px',
    }, 1500);
    }

);
```

Comment: The difference in speed between .bind('click') and .click() is negligible. Aslo, don't use native js where you can, use what's optimal in terms of speed/readability. slider[0].style.width won't save you even a millisecond here.

Comment: @Alexey First of all bind have more functionality and is faster, speaking against its use is silly. Second of all http://jsperf.com/jq-css-vs-dom-style check the tests before you speak - native JS/DOM manipulation is a lot faster even if mixed with jQuery. And things add up, bit here bit there and suddenly your page works better on shitty netbooks and old PCs - not everybody is a developer with core i7 - I'm sharing tips on GOOD PRACTICES so please don't advocate against those if you offer nothing better in exchange.

Comment: @Alexey Lebedev: hope you did run these tests - on FF3.6 jQuery/CSS manipulation is 93% slower then native, on IE the differences are going to be even larger - you should revisit your approach to web development or at least keep it to yourself - much love

Comment: @Tom "jQuery/CSS manipulation is 93% slower then native" - actually it's browser reflow that takes most of the time anyway, but ok, let's agree on this one. But we're talking a single call here, not thousands of them as in mousemove handlers (where I rarely use jQuery myself). What you're advocating is  premature optimization. I have no intention to bring you over to my point of view, just explaining this is not the case when things add up. Why sacrifice readability for a doubtful speed gain?

Comment: @Tom Great points and elegant code. After implementing I've modified it a bit. Set it so that the arrow that's fading in waits until the animation of the slider has completed. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: @Daniel Redwood: You are welcome, we are here to share the love :)